# Alternate mysql table row background colour

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add alternate row colours to my mysql table. I am using this code to echo the table structure

```
//creating our table    
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</h3></th>";
        echo "<th>First Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
        echo "<th>email</th>";
        echo "<th>street</th>";
        echo "<th>Suburb</th>";
        echo "<th>State</th>";
        echo "<th>Action</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

So far I have tried

```
//creating our table    
    echo "<tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }>";
```

and also adding this to external style sheet

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }>";
```

but neither approach works. How might I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```
th:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }
```

You want to make the background-color of `<th>` light grey, not `<tr>`

Comment: My mistake I was just seeing if I could change alternate table heading columns as a test of the basic idea which worked. However when I tried to apply the css to table row  tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; } it does not work

Comment: I did not read your reply properly. If I use th:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; } it makes alternate columns in table header alternate colours successfully, but when I use t:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; } no styling is applied

Comment: I resolved this by removing all table td css and adding css to table tr plus a few other minor css adjustments

Comment: If you resolved it, I think you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

At che-azeh's suggestion I am reposting my comment as an answer I resolved this by removing all table td css and adding css to table tr plus a few other minor css adjustments